# Cookie-Based Authentication Security of Popular Websites

Tags: authentication, web-application, cookies

Let's take Google and other popular bank websites which uses cookie.

I've been working with a website using Angular which uses Laravel as an API. Data are stored in cookies which is vulnerable in client side including the JWT.

For websites using cookie-based authentication, what security implementation and practices they do to protect and secure the data from any attack aside from setting the security flags and options of cookie?

Here are some of specific cookie attacks:

1. CSRF, cookie
   poisoning
2. XSS
3. Session fixation
4. Eavesdropping,
   cookie hijacking/stealing
5. Cookie injection
   from related hostnames
6. Cookie eviction
7. Direct cookie injection
8. TCP/IP hijacking

**How popular websites and bank websites handle these attacks in order to protect the data stored in the cookies?**

Comment: You can't secure data from any attack. You can only secure something against something specific. If you list what attacks you had in mind, then it's possible to say what countermeasures can be taken. As it stands now, your question is too broad.

Comment: @MechMK1 That's true. Thank you for pointing out. I updated my question to be more specific with the cookie attacks.

Answer (score 2):

## How can I protect myself against CSRF attacks?

OWASP offers a great [cheatsheet](https://cheatsheetseries.owasp.org/cheatsheets/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet.html), which aims at providing the basics of CSRF protection. Here is their summary of CSRF protection:

> We recommend token based CSRF defense (either stateful/stateless) as a primary defense to mitigate CSRF in your applications. Only for highly sensitive operations, we also recommend a user interaction based protection (either re-authentication/one-time token, detailed in section 6.5) along with token based mitigation.
>
> As a defense-in-depth measure, consider implementing one mitigation from Defense in Depth Mitigations section (you can choose the mitigation that fits your ecosystem considering the issues mentioned under them). These defense-in-depth mitigation techniques are not recommended to be used by themselves (without token based mitigation) for mitigating CSRF in your applications.

The basic gist is that you want to send the user a token with your application, and the user will have to send that token back with every request. If an attacker would try to get you to send a request when visiting their website, the attacker would have to "guess" that token, which may not be possible if the token is created well.

## How can I prevent XSS vulnerabilities?

XSS, also known as Cross-Site Scripting, is an injection attack. Basically, an attacker is able to "inject" scripts into your website, causing the victim to execute them.

The way to prevent them is to encode your output properly for the context into which you put *any* user-supplied data. Input validation is seen as an additional step, depending on its complexity. For instance, checking if an input is a number is trivial to do. Checking if an input is valid XML is more difficult.

Since you specifically asked about cookies, setting the `HttpOnly`-flag is an effective Defense-in-Depth measure to prevent an attacker from reading the contents of cookies, even if an XSS vulnerability can be exploited.

Again, OWASP offers an excellent [cheatsheet](https://cheatsheetseries.owasp.org/cheatsheets/Cross_Site_Scripting_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet.html).

## Session Fixation

Session Fixation is a problem in regards to session management. The attack works the following:

1. An attcker visits a vulnerable website and is assigned a session (e.g. `session=abcd`)
2. The attacker then sends the victim a link to the website, which establishes the **same** session. (e.g. `https://example.com?session=abcd`)
3. The victim then logs into the application.
4. The server now considers the session `abcd` to be an authenticated session with the victims credentials.
5. The attacker now has access to the victim's account, as the attack knows the session ID of the victim.

Again, this attack doesn't really have anything to do with cookies, and more with session management. There is also not really any "generic" advice, as it highly depends on the session management mechanism.

## How can I prevent eavesdropping?

By using TLS and ensuring that cookies are only sent via secure channels. For this case, setting the `Secure`-flag instructs the browser to only send cookies via HTTPS, never plain HTTP.

## How can I prevent Cookie Eviction?

According to I. Ristic's *"Bulletproof SSL and TLS: Understanding and Deploying SSL/TLS and PKI to Secure Servers and Web Applications"*, Cookie Eviction is an attack against the user's browser. Browsers limit cookies in various ways, such as the size of the individual cookies, the amount of cookies per domain, or the total amount of cookies.

The attack consists of the attacker sending countless bogus cookies to the browser, causing it to delete older, but legitimate cookies, until eventually, only their bogus cookies are left.

This can be considered a Denial-of-Service attack, but one that can be remediated quite easily by deleting all bogus cookies and not visiting the attacker's malicious website(s) anymore.

You can, frankly, not really do anything against that. It's up to browser vendors to prevent this kind of attack.

## About TCP/IP Hijacking

This TCP (and even more IP) is far below in the OSI Layers, and has absolutely nothing to do with cookies.

---

I am uncertain what you mean by "Cookie Injection by related hostnames" or "Direct Cookie Injection". Could you please elaborate further on that?

Comment: What I mean regarding Session Fixation is storing session identifiers in cookies. In TCP/IP Hijacking, an attacker uses a user’s cookie to access the user’s session. Session timeouts are incorrectly configured.

Comment: In "Cookie Injection from related host-names", sibling domains (for an example foo.website.com) are able to set cookies with Domain attribute value of another domain (for an example website.com) and overwrite an existing cookie set by another domain (for an example bar.website.com). For "direct cookie injection", secure and insecure cookies may locate in the same namespace. Whenever an attacker captures plain text transaction from victim’s target web site, the attacker replies the http response with arbitrary cookies.

Comment: @daniela Session Fixation requires quite a few things to be possible. For one, the server needs to give out sessions before any authentication is done. Second, the application needs to be built in a way to allow an attacker to "force" a user to use a specific session. This isn't directly related to cookies in any way. As for TCP/IP: This is why you use TLS. Again, TCP has nothing to do with cookies.

Comment: @daniela As for cookie injection, if an attacker were to override the legitimate session cookie with "garbage" data, then they would effectively log the user out. Solution: Don't use plain HTTP. Ever.